# Making my FindLibDL CMake script not report failure for a false boolean value

Tags: cmake

I'm usiing a [FindLibDL CMake module](https://github.com/eyalroz/libgiddy/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindLibDL.cmake) which, among other things, determines some boolean value regarding underscores:

```
# ...
CHECK_C_SOURCE_RUNS("#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void testfunc() {}
int main() {
  testfunc();
  if (dlsym(0, \"_testfunc\") != (void*)0) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  } else {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
}" LIBDL_NEEDS_UNDERSCORE)

mark_as_advanced(LIBDL_INCLUDE_DIRS LIBDL_LIBRARIES LIBDL_NEEDS_UNDERSCORE)
```

The thing is, if underscores are not needed, CMake reports a Failure for `LIBDL_NEEDS_UNDERSCORE`. How can I make it so that I still determine the same value and still not reported as a Failure?

Comment: If underscores aren't need, this var contains `FALSE`. What's the problem? It is working as you intended.

Comment: @arrowd: The problem is the CMake's console output tells me something has failed, while nothing fails, it's just `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

As @arrowd points, it is just how [CHECK_C_SOURCE_RUNS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/CheckCSourceRuns.html) macro works: if compiled program returns 0, it reports *Success*, otherwise it reports *Failed*.

If you want other output, you may use [try_run](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/try_run.html) command directly.

---

E.g. with `try_run` you may achive this behavior:

- if underscore is needed, output is

  ```
  Check whether 'dl' requires underscore - Yes
  ```
- if underscore is not needed, output is

  ```
  Check whether 'dl' requires underscore - No
  ```
- if error occurs during the check, output is

  ```
  Check whether 'dl' requires underscore - Failed
  ```

Comment: Oh, wait - the `try_run` command takes a source file; but I don't have a source file, I only have the module. Are you suggesting I create a temporary file and use that? Or is there a trick not involving a temporary file?

Comment: Create temporary source file. [Implementation of CHECK_C_SOURCE_RUNS](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CheckCSourceRuns.cmake) uses exactly this way.